# How to upload and view an image file from server

Tags: angular, express, multer

I am using multer to upload files. It gets uploaded to "Public" folder which is present outside "dist" folder.

I want to display the image after uploading using the uploaded path as src.

I know this question might be silly. But I am not able to think of anything.

Need help guys !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the path in your app.js file.

like this:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/Public')));
```

OR

```
app.use('/public', express.static(process.cwd() + '/Public'));
```

Then you will be able to access it any where in angular like this:

```
<img src="/public/image_name.jpg" />
```

Comment: Cool one. Thanks :)